# Windows command to view all DSNs?

Tags: odbc, datasource, dsn

I have some VB code that connects to a DSN (data source) setup on this Windows machine. The code looks like:

```
Dim myConnection As OdbcConnection = New OdbcConnection()
myConnection.ConnectionString = "DSN=MYALERTS"
```

It still works & connects, however the user who set this up is no longer around. I need to view/edit this, but when I go into "ODBC Data Source Administrator" in Windows I see no DSNs listed. I assume this is because I'm under my own user. Even under "System DSN" tab, the list is blank.

Is there a Windows command (or even VB code) to view all DSNs on this Windows 7 machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to view all DSNs in the registry:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SOFTWARE->ODBC->ODBC.INI

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is a little dated, but perhaps will help someone.  When using the ODBC Manager on a 64 bit Windows OS, you will only see 64 ODBC connections.  If the connection you are seeking was setup for 32 bit, you can browse down to \Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe applet and manage the legacy 32 bit DSNs.  This is helpful when working with applications that are compiled to target 32 bit.

Answer (score 3):

This prints *user* and *system* DSN (data source name) from Windows registry.

```
Module ModuleDsn

    Public Enum DataSourceType
        System
        User
    End Enum

    Sub Main()
        Dim SU As SortedList = GetDataSourceNames(DataSourceType.User)
        Dim SS As SortedList = GetDataSourceNames(DataSourceType.System)
        Dim count As Integer = SU.Count + SS.Count
        Dim mKeys As [String]() = New String(count - 1) {}
        SU.Keys.CopyTo(mKeys, 0)
        SS.Keys.CopyTo(mKeys, SU.Keys.Count)
        For i As Integer = 0 To mKeys.Length - 1
            Console.WriteLine(mKeys(i))
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Function GetDataSourceNames(ByVal dsnType As DataSourceType) As System.Collections.SortedList
        Dim dsnList As New System.Collections.SortedList()
        Dim reg As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Nothing

        If dsnType = DataSourceType.User Then
            reg = (Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser).OpenSubKey("Software")
        Else
            reg = (Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine).OpenSubKey("Software")
        End If

        If reg IsNot Nothing Then
            reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC")
            If reg IsNot Nothing Then
                reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC.INI")
                If reg IsNot Nothing Then
                    reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC Data Sources")
                    If reg IsNot Nothing Then
                        For Each sName As String In reg.GetValueNames()
                            dsnList.Add(sName, DataSourceType.User)
                        Next
                    End If
                    Try
                        reg.Close()
                    Catch
                    End Try
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Return dsnList
    End Function

End Module
```